# find the multiplicative factor for get a specific amount of sum on sin

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, summation

i am not a math guru so please sorry if this is a silly question. i'm not sure on how to latexize this question so i've done a spreadsheets with openoffice (and i'm interest also in the best way to write it in latex).

i want to find a multiplicative factor \beta to get a certain sin sum in n step. like this: find beta for

$$\sum_{\substack{0\le \theta\le \Pi}} \beta sin(x)$$

if theta goes from 0 to Pi in n step. say, for example if beta = 11, n = 10 so

[image]

the sum is 62.3841

now, if i have n step and i want the sum is alpha .. how to calculate beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest $$\beta=\frac{\alpha}{\sum \sin x}.$$